# Leaflet-image plugin - render Label or Legend generated in a canvas over the map?

Tags: canvas, leaflet, legend, html2canvas

As said in the Leaflet-image plugin requirements :

> This library **does not rasterize HTML** because browsers cannot rasterize HTML. Therefore, L.divIcon and other HTML-based features of a map, like zoom controls or legends, are not included in the output, because they are HTML

And what about a Label or a Legend generated in a canvas over the map ?

I tried to do it, dynamically creating an SVG Legend, rendering it in a canvas with canvg library.
The canvas appears well over the map (by a L.control => a **DIV** containing the canvas)

As I suspected Leaflet-image does not render it.

But I think it's possible, because Leaflet-Image is able to generate an image from a map rendered in canvas.